# Can migration be a synonym of travel?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have a tag for [travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) with wiki guidance that reads:

> For questions about the movement of people between locations, includes
>   migration.
>
> This tag is for questions about the movement of people between
>   locations. This includes questions about migration and similar styles
>   of journey.

I found when looking for a tag for migration, but it took me several tries, as nothing comes up when searching for "migration."

I don't see a need for an additional tag, but it would be very helpful if [migration](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) could be a synonym of [travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel).

I have enough rep on [travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) to propose synonyms but, when I tried to do so, I got an error message saying:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a
>   synonym!

I propose that the synonym comes to pass.  If possible, I'd love to get the [Synonymizer badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer) in the process (yeah yeah, badge hunters).  Might this mean tagging a post with [migration](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) to create it and then proposing the synonym and hoping enough people see it and vote on it?  Crazy path...

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the two are synonyms, or, in other words, that they can always be used interchangeably?

I.e. (space) tourism could surely use a travel tag, but has nothing to do with migration.

That is also what I infer from the tag wiki you quote: migration is a subset of travel. All migrations are travels, not all travels are migrations.

Comment: "All migrations are travels, not all travels are migrations."  I completely agree.  It's also common to have tags that represent a broad category and then have synonyms to help people find the sub-categories (so they don't keep recreating new tags that we don't actually need, because they wouldn't be used enough to justify them and the broader tag works just fine).  For example: fantasy and magic are not the same thing by a longshot, but fantasy is a synonym of magic.  And I just successfully lobbied you all to make acoustics a synonym of audio.

Comment: If the synonym is from migration to travel, then what matters is whether all migrations are travel.  The reverse doesn't matter because nobody's starting with travel and ending up at migration.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, I concur with *All migrations are travels, not all travels are migrations.*  "Migration" presupposes that the trip is one-way and that one is bringing one's wealth, one's important papers, one's household and one's livelihood in an effort to transplant all that in the new location.  "Travel" doesn't presuppose that at all, and in fact usually indicates a there and back situation.

If you were to create a migration tag, I wouldn't suggest synonymising it with travel and if alerted wouldn't vote for that for the reason stated.

In all honesty, I'd actually question the need for a "travel" tag at all...